# JavaScript this from jQuery this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get JavaScript this from jQuery this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: What is a 'jQuery this'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` == `this`, whatever `this` is.

`this` is a not jquery it is a special, somewhat convoluted, javascript keyword that describes the current scope of execution.

your challenge may be determining or controlling what `this` is.

Comment: I think that the OP actually wants to know something else

Answer (score 8):

There is:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var jqueryobject = $(this);
   var domelement   = this;
});
```

Within such a closure, `this` always represent the native `DOM element` which must/can be `wrapped` into a jQuery object.

If you already got a jQuery object and need to get the `DOM element` either use

```
var DOMelement = $(this)[0];
```

or

```
var DOMelement = $(this).get(0);
```

Since jQuery objects are `array like objects` you can always grab them with standard array access `[]` notation. The jQuery method [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) will actually do the same. With both ways, you'll receive the `DOM element` at that array position.

**General** - what is `this` ?

- `this` contains a reference to the object of invocation
- `this` allows a method to know what object it is concerned with
- `this` allows a single function object to service many functions
- So `this` is the most important part of all protoypal inheritance things

Comment: but is a memeber of the jquery `this`? `that` is the question.

Comment: As an aside, I _really_ don't like using the array accessor to get to the DOM element. Totally unintuitive.

Comment: @code poet: `this` is a native javascript keyword, actually always holding the scope of a javascript `block`. So no, `this` is no jQuery thing.

Comment: whoa, hold on, a member of the jquery *could* be `this` but is it? that is my point. OP question is setting us up to play 'who's on first'

Comment: If "this" is already a jquery object, and you need to get the DOM element, you do NOT want to do: $(this)[0].  Yes, it works, but you're doing extra work.  "this" is ALREADY a jquery object.  Don't do $(this).  Just do this[0] or this.get(0).  No need to jquery a jquery.

Comment: @Samuel: not in an event handler. Within a jQuery event handler `this` represents the `DOM element`, see http://jsbin.com/ogofi3/2/edit

Comment: @jAndy: I realize that's how event handlers work in jquery.  But your statement said "If you already got a jQuery object and need to get the DOM element", and then said to use $(this), which is incorrect.  It works, but it's incorrect.

Comment: jAndy, arguing with @sam, except in *rare* occasions, is an exercise in edutainment. go ahead and play the game but don't fool yourself into thinking you are going to win. *most* of the time, that is. ;-) *yes, you may quote me on that*

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're asking for here, but I'll give it a shot. Firstly, remember that jQuery is just a series of functions written in Javascript. The `this` keyword is literally the same in "both" contexts.

Perhaps you want to get the actual DOM element instead of the jQuery object? You can use `.get()`:

```
// let's say there's a single paragraph element
var obj = $('p');   // obj is a jQuery object 
var dom = obj.get(0);  // dom is a DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access `this` (DOM element) instead of `$(this)` (jquery object).