# Why does my jQuery work in Meteor's onRendered but not in the events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor-blaze

I have a hamburger that animates when you click on it. I am able to successfully make it work if I place it in the onRendered section but it will not work in the events section. The hamburger becomes unresponsive if I try to run the code in Template.events.

onRendered Code

```
Template.Top_navbar.onRendered(function () {
 var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");

    $hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
        $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = $(this);
        el.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 300);
    });
});
```

events code

```
Template.Top_navbar.events({
    'click .hamburger': function (event) {
        $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
        event.preventDefault();
        var el = $(this);
        el.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 300);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is where you're going wrong...

In Meteor onRendered callbacks, `this` refers to the template instance, and in events `this` refers to the data context of the element that triggered the event. So `this` is different depending on where it's used.

But your further complication is that your `this` in the onRendered callback is inside the jquery event handler, so in that context it refers to the DOM element, not the template instance - which is why it actually works. (This is general javascript, not Meteor-specific. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3146830/3783510))

For clarity (and sanity) I avoid `this` where I can and try to be more explicit - so you could just replace `$(this)` with `$(".hamburger")`

Comment: Also you've got `function(e)` in onRendered but you want `function(event)`